# How to specify which keys CapsLock affects?

Tags: keyboard-layout, capslock

Using Maverick, I am not able to get the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behaviour I want: I would like it to affect essentially the alphabetical, numerical, and punctuation keys, i.e. **all** the keys that *print* something (as opposed to, say, the arrow keys), but **only** them.

To illuminate this with an example: when writing code that uses % as the symbol for a comment, I want to be able to position the cursor at the start of a range of lines I want to comment out, then hit <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, then iteratively hit the <kbd>5</kbd> key (using QWERTZ, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> gives %) and the arrow down key, so that I can quickly place a % at the start of the lines.

Ubuntu in default configuration takes CapsLock literally, so that it affects only alphabetic keys. Under Preferences/Keyboard/Layout/Options I can make it act as a pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but then the action of the arrow keys is to select text. All the other options available are equivalent to one of these two in my case.

Is it possible to somehow get this behaviour? This is standard in Windows.

Edit: @Mikel: I use English language with German keyboard layout. Yes, by googling I found out about this Belgian problem and the fix, but I hoped that there was an easier way, as I just want the Windows behaviour. Let's see whether I get it to work.

Comment: What language do you use?  You might be able to adapt the solution for Belgian to your needs.  http://launchpadlibrarian.net/29195040/mswindows-capslock.patch

Comment: ^ I'm new here. Why is this a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @djeikyb ask that on meta :)

Comment: @Roland It's half rhetorical. That is a comment, admittedly with room for expansion, that I would award as The Answer if I were the questioner.

Comment: ahh I get you now. The part about being new made me suggest you go to meta :)

Comment: I've never seen this option as standard in Windows. Little OT, but where is it?

Answer (score 3):

Answers in the comment lead to the impression that there is no easy GNOME setting to toggle. Vote up mikel's answer in the comments, not mine: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/29195040/mswindows-capslock.patch to adapt the belgian solution.

Comment: Think the policy is to use answers, not comments, on askubuntu.  You can't accept a comment as an answer for example.  Mikel should be encouraged to submit his comment as an answer.

Comment: I agree. Hello, Mikel!